# Wifi connected, no internet until modem restarted [Ubuntu 14.04]

Tags: 14.04, wireless, internet, atheros

This question has been asked repeatedly, but none of the suggestions out there have worked for me. So I would appreciate any help specific to my case.

Even when Wifi is connected, I don't have internet connection. Usually this is fixed when I restart the modem (not the computer or the connection on my computer) and then the internet connection persists for about 30 to 90 minutes before I repeat the same procedure. All other computers on this network don't seem to have this problem. And my computer has this exact same issue with some other wifi networks (not all of them).

While I'm connected to the problem wifi network, here are some details:

```
~$ iwconfig
 eth0      no wireless extensions.

 lo        no wireless extensions.

 wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"o2-WLAN27"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.427 GHz  Access Point: 9C:80:DF:61:E7:9E   
      Bit Rate=19.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=39/70  Signal level=-71 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:498   Missed beacon:0
```

The next command :

```
~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

The next command:

```
~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: AR8152 v2.0 Fast Ethernet
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: c1
   serial: b8:70:f4:15:40:c3
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.1-NAPI latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:43 memory:d0500000-d053ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
  *-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 01
   serial: 68:a3:c4:9a:4f:96
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.13.0-125-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:17 memory:d0400000-d040ffff
```